# Will an "old" MiKTeX version receive the "new" LaTeX?

Tags: miktex, distributions, update

I just moved from Mac to Windows and have to adjust a little bit. I am forced to use MiKteX 21.2 now (even though 22.3 is out already). Will this distribution install the new 2022 version of LaTeX that was published yesterday? (I hope this question is not bordering on stupidity...)

Comment: today a new texlive was released, that is not a latex version but a texsystem. Miktex will never install that. To check if your miktex installs a current latex, simply run the update manager and then check which latex version you have (current is LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1).

Comment: having used TeXLive for years now, I never realized that! I kept thinking that the new TeXLive version coincides with yearly LaTeX-milestones! I think my reason for this was precisely that with every new TeXLive version, the distribution folder gets a new 2020, 2021, 2022 folder... Alright. this was news to me. thanks for clarifying, @UlrikeFischer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Want to make that an answer?